# Node.js- "npm install express" error:0906D06C :PEM routines : PEM_read_bio npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cmd, npm

I have installed node.js and it has npm installed along with it. In my windows command prompt,when i write "npm install express", it gives me the following error.How to resolve this?

> C:\Users>npm -v
>
> 2.11.2
>
> C:\Users>npm install express
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs \node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "express"
>
> npm ERR! node v0.12.5
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
>
> npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\npm-debug.log

Comment: Did you try running your command prompt as an Administrator? Right click > Run as administrator.

Comment: I tried in administration mode. The error is still the same.

Comment: i have been facing the same issue. Also, note, you should also not be able to install any module through npm install

Answer (score 2):

I also got same problem after setting registry problem got resolved.

```
cmd>> npm set registry registry.npmjs.org 
cmd>> npm install
```

it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Please use cmd>> npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
after that try cmd>> npm install
it worked for me.

Comment: Please take more care in writing your answers. 4 indents to show code or other monospaced text, `![](imageurl)` to show images - do post code rather than images