# Getting error while angular2 setup

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Getting the following error while Angular2 setup. I tried to reinstall the node twice but getting the same error. Please help.

> ******Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200] (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. C:\Users\Me-PC>npm install -g
>   @angular/cli npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
>   \npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli" npm ERR! node
>   v6.11.3 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line npm ERR! npm ERR! If you need
>   help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues npm ERR! Please include the
>   following file with any support request: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Me-PC\npm-debug.log C:\Users\Me-PC>******

Comment: Please, edit your question to add formatting to error text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js- "npm install express" error:0906D06C :PEM routines : PEM\_read\_bio npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048197/node-js-npm-install-express-error0906d06c-pem-routines-pem-read-bio-npm)